# codeigniter pagination does not limit the returned rows from db

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, pagination

Hi I am currently working on the pagination of my project. What I want to do is to limit the returned records from the database by 3 rows per page. Apparently, the pagination links were echoed but still it returns all the rows from the database without limiting the records by 3.

Here's my code:

Model

```
function fetchItemsOrderBy($table, $data = NULL,$column,$order,$limit, $start){
        if ($data != NULL){
            $this->db->where($data);
        }

        $this->db->order_by($column, $order);
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
    }
```

View

```
<section class="review-section">
        <div class="container">
            <?php
                if($article = $this->NCCT_Model->fetchItems('articles')):
                foreach ($article as $articleEntry): 
            ?>
            <div class="review-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="review-pic">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/"?>Articles_Attachments/<?=$articleEntry->attachment?>" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="review-content text-box text-white">
                            <div class="top-meta"><?=date("F j, Y",$articleEntry->posted_on)?> / in <a style="color: #ffae42;"><?=$articleEntry->category?></a></div>
                            <h3> <?=$articleEntry->title?></h3>
                            <p style="color: #2e2e2e"><?=substr($articleEntry->overview, 0, 500)?>.....</p>
                            <a href="<?php if($checker) { echo base_url().'UserHome/announcementsReadMore/',$articleEntry->entry_id; } else { echo base_url().'Home/announcementsReadMore/',$articleEntry->entry_id; } ?>" class="read-more">Read More  <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/"?>img/icons/double-arrow.png" alt="#"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
            <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Controller

```
public function announcements(){
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url()."Home/announcements";
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->NCCT_Model->get_count('articles');
        $config['per_page'] = 3;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

        $checker = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        $data = [
            'title' => "Articles and Announcements",
            'checker' => $checker,
            'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
            'articles' => $this->NCCT_Model->fetchItemsOrderBy('articles', null, 'entry_id', 'ASC', $config['per_page'], $page),
        ];
        $this->load->view('pages/includes/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/articlesAndAnnouncements');
        $this->load->view('pages/includes/footer');
    }
```

Hope you could help me out solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try not to call any model methods in view. That's a bad practice. You are violating the purpose of MVC architecture.

Comment: Which url are you calling your request on? 
Because the query param is taking in the $page variable. 
What is $config['per_page'] holding as value and  what value is $page ?
what DB library are you using and what doest it say about the Limit ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove from view

```
if($article = $this->NCCT_Model->fetchItems('articles')):
```

And change:

```
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

To

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I just realized that there is actually no need for an if-else statement as I already declared the fetchItemsOrderBy in the controller to get the records from the articles table, I missed that one. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Okay! no problem